# Loading architecture from model.json file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

I am trying to load the model architecture from the model.json file but I am getting the below error :

`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.image' has no attribute 'resize_bilinear'`

This is how i am loading the json file :

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
with open("model.json", "r") as file:
  model_json = file.read()
loaded_model = model_from_json(model_json)
```

i have downloaded this json file from this github repo
`https://github.com/janzd/EAST`

Thanks.

Comment: Where is that `model.json` in the repo. ?

Comment: please put all codes in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this model is being trained using tensorflow version 1.x because this api `'resize_bilinear'` was only available in `TF 1.x`. To avoid this error, please try again running your code by disabling eager execution using code below:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

or you can use the below line of code on top of your code to switch to TF 1.x:

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```